# How to shorten the absolute path when using webpack v.2?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I want to use absolute path resolving rules in my project, but when I import a module like this

```
import Component from "/home/components/Component.js"
```

it cannot be resolved by webpack, only this works:

```
 import Component from "/users/username/home/components/component.js"
```

I tried to specify context in my webpack.config, but it made no sense:

```
context: __dirname
```

Since I work on windows how do I change my webpack.config to be able to import modules like in the first snippet? In other words how to change my absolute path root for webpack v.2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resolve.alias` to shorten import paths:

**webpack.config.js**

```
...
resolve: {
  alias: {
    home: '/users/username/home/',
  },
},
...
```

Then you will be able to import a module like this:

```
import Component from "home/components/Component.js"
```

More information on the official documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/